# How to store a GeoJSON file in a parquet format

Tags: python, geojson, jupyter-notebook, geoparquet, fastparquet

I have a large GeoJSON file which I store and read as follows:

```
geomap.to_file(path_to_output + 'geomap_cleaned.geojson', driver="GeoJSON")

geomap = import_geojson(path_to_data, path_to_cadgis, 'geomap_cleaned.geojson')
```

My issue is that geomap is a large file (1G) and the kernel in my Jupyter Notebook crashes most of time when I try to read it.

I made an attempt to save the GeoJSON file in a fast parquet format (my aim is to make things faster and more optimised)

```
geomap.to_parquet(path_to_data + 'geomap_cleaned.gzip', compression='GZIP', engine='pyarrow')
```

but i get an error

```
ArrowInvalid: Cannot parse URI: './Source data/geomap.gzip'
```

How can I solve this problem? And how can I make sure the geometries, when stored in parquet format, are not corrupted?

I also installed successfully `geoparquet` by using `pip install geoparquet` but when i save the file as :

```
geomap.to_geoparquet('geomap_cleaned.geoparquet')
```

I get an error

TypeError: Object of type CRS is not JSON serializable

What is wrong here?

Comment: pretty sure you need to install pyarrow library. you can also use geopandas not in jupyter to convert it to geoparquet

Comment: It does not work with pyarrow i already tried   ....can you suggest a code please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Geopandas to covert the geojson to geoparquet. Sometimes you need to explicitly set the CRS, for this example I am assuming its 4326.

```
import geopandas as gpd
geojson_fn='test'
geoparquet_fn='output_geoparquet'
gdf=gpd.read_file(f'{geojson_fn}.geojson')
gdf.set_crs(epsg=4326)
gdf_projected.to_parquet(f'{geoparquet_fn}.parquet')
```

Comment: I succesfully saved the file in a parquet format as specified but the geometries were corrupted.

Comment: elaborate by what you mean, is your data supposed to be in 4326?

Comment: When I follow your method, i get geometries as backslash and some weird numbers which make no sense. I think what I will do is to encode the geometries  as `wkt`, drop the geometries, save as parquet. Then read the parquet and decode the `wkt` to retrieve geometries

Comment: try and view the geojson on a map. if that is invalid then something is up with your input data. converting from geojson to geoparquet is a straightforward process